# Store logs in file if logging in database fails

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-web-api2, serilog

I was working on Logging using Serilog in .net core web api 7.
Logs are successfully getting stored in database

But my question is, if database logging fails then that log should get stored in a file
No idea of how to achieve it.
Any help would be great
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a issue related:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67436306/c-sharp-serilog-conditional-logging-if-one-fails/67437033#67437033

Comment: Your requirement would be achieved more easier with Nlog FallbackGroup https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FallbackGroup-target

Comment: Thank you, and even through Elmah, it's easy as compared to Serilog.
We are in the Analysis phase and need to identify which is better-fit elmah or Serilog.